# Website streatches backgrond image on mobile

Tags: css, html, mobile-website

```css
@charset "utf-8";


@import url("fontawesome-4.6.3.min.css");
@import url("custom.flexslider.css");
@import url("framework.css");

/* Rows
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.row0{border-bottom:1px solid;}
.row1, .row1 a{}
.row2, .row2 a{}
.row3, .row3 a{}
.row4, .row4 a{}
.row5, .row5 a{}


/* Top Bar
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#topbar{padding:15px 0; font-size:62%; text-transform:uppercase;}

#topbar *{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#topbar ul li{display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; padding-right:15px; border-right:1px solid;}
#topbar ul li:last-child{margin-right:0; padding-right:0; border-right:none;}
#topbar i{margin:0 5px 0 0; line-height:normal;}


/* Header
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#header{}

#header #logo{margin:30px 0 0 0;}
#header #logo h1{margin:0; padding:0; font-size:22px; text-transform:uppercase;}


/* Page Intro
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#pageintro{padding:150px 0 300px;}

#pageintro li article{display:block; max-width:100%; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
#pageintro li article *{margin:0;}
#pageintro li p:first-of-type{margin-bottom:10px; font-style:italic;}
#pageintro li .heading{margin-bottom:30px; font-size:3rem; word-wrap:break-word;}
#pageintro li p:nth-of-type(2){line-height:1.5rem;}
#pageintro li footer{margin-top:40px;}

#pageintro footer form{display:block; position:relative; max-width:50%; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;}
#pageintro footer input, #pageintro footer button{display:block; height:44px; border:none; border-radius:22px;}
#pageintro footer input{width:100%; padding:5px 40px 5px 15px;}
#pageintro footer button{position:absolute; top:1px; right:1px; width:42px; height:42px; font-size:16px; cursor:pointer; border-radius:50%;}
#pageintro footer button em{display:none;}


/* Content Area
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.container{padding:80px 0;}

/* Content */
.container .content{}

.sectiontitle{display:block; margin-bottom:80px;}
.sectiontitle *{margin:0;}

#introblocks{position:relative; z-index:1;}
#introblocks > ul{display:block; margin:-200px 0 80px;}
#introblocks > ul > li{text-align:center;}
#introblocks > ul > li > article{display:inline-block; width:100%; max-width:320px; text-align:left;}
#introblocks > ul > li > article > div{padding:30px 20px;}
#introblocks > ul > li > article > div *{margin:0; padding:0;}
#introblocks > ul > li > article > div .heading{margin-bottom:10px; font-size:1.2rem;}
#introblocks > ul > li > article footer{border-top:1px solid;}
#introblocks > ul > li > article footer a{display:block; position:relative; width:100%; height:39px; line-height:39px; padding:0 20px; text-transform:uppercase;}
#introblocks > ul > li > article footer a::after{position:absolute; top:0; right:0; height:100%; padding:0 15px; font-family:"FontAwesome"; content:"\f105"; border-left:1px solid;}

#newsletter input, #newsletter button{border:1px solid; border-radius:22px;}
#newsletter input{display:block; width:100%; padding:8px;}
#newsletter button{padding:8px 18px 10px; border:none; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:700; cursor:pointer;}

/* Comments */
#comments ul{margin:0 0 40px 0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#comments li{margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:15px;}
#comments .avatar{float:right; margin:0 0 10px 10px; padding:3px; border:1px solid;}
#comments address{font-weight:bold;}
#comments time{font-size:smaller;}
#comments .comcont{display:block; margin:0; padding:0;}
#comments .comcont p{margin:10px 5px 10px 0; padding:0;}

#comments form{display:block; width:100%;}
#comments input, #comments textarea{width:100%; padding:10px; border:1px solid;}
#comments textarea{overflow:auto;}
#comments div{margin-bottom:15px;}
#comments input[type="submit"], #comments input[type="reset"]{display:inline-block; width:auto; min-width:150px; margin:0; padding:8px 5px; cursor:pointer;}

/* Sidebar */
.container .sidebar{}

.sidebar .sdb_holder{margin-bottom:50px;}
.sidebar .sdb_holder:last-child{margin-bottom:0;}


/* Footer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#footer{padding:80px 0; text-align:center;}

#footer .heading, #footer ul{margin-bottom:30px;}
#footer > ul:last-of-type{margin-bottom:0;}
#footer .faico a{border-radius:50%;}


/* Copyright
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#copyright{padding:20px 0;}
#copyright *{margin:0; padding:0;}


/* Transition Fade
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
*, *::before, *::after{transition:all .0s ease-in-out;}
#mainnav form *{transition:none !important;}





/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
nav ul, nav ol{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}

#mainnav, #breadcrumb, .sidebar nav{line-height:normal;}
#mainnav .drop::after, #mainnav li li .drop::after, #breadcrumb li a::after, .sidebar nav a::after{position:absolute; font-family:"FontAwesome"; font-size:10px; line-height:10px;}

/* Top Navigation */
#mainnav{}
#mainnav ul{text-transform:uppercase;}
#mainnav ul ul{z-index:9999; position:absolute; width:180px; text-transform:none;}
#mainnav ul ul ul{left:180px; top:0;}
#mainnav li{display:inline-block; position:relative; margin:0 15px 0 0; padding:0;}
#mainnav li:last-child{margin-right:0;}
#mainnav li li{width:50%; margin:0;}
#mainnav li a{display:block; padding:30px 0;}
#mainnav li li a{border:solid; border-width:0 0 1px 0;}
#mainnav .drop{padding-left:15px;}
#mainnav li li a, #mainnav li li .drop{display:block; margin:0; padding:10px 15px;}
#mainnav .drop::after, #mainnav li li .drop::after{content:"\f0d7";}
#mainnav .drop::after{top:35px; left:5px;}
#mainnav li li .drop::after{top:15px; left:5px;}
#mainnav ul ul{visibility:hidden; opacity:0;}
#mainnav ul li:hover > ul{visibility:visible; opacity:1;}

#mainnav form{display:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
#mainnav form select, #mainnav form select option{display:block; cursor:pointer; outline:none;}
#mainnav form select{width:100%; padding:5px; border:1px solid;}
#mainnav form select option{margin:5px; padding:0; border:none;}

/* Breadcrumb */
#breadcrumb{padding:120px 0 30px;}
#breadcrumb ul{margin:0 0 30px 0; padding:0 0 8px 0; list-style:none; text-transform:uppercase; border-bottom:1px solid;}
#breadcrumb li{display:inline-block; margin:0 6px 0 0; padding:0;}
#breadcrumb li a{display:block; position:relative; margin:0; padding:0 12px 0 0; font-size:12px;}
#breadcrumb li a::after{top:3px; right:0; content:"\f101";}
#breadcrumb li:last-child a{margin:0; padding:0;}
#breadcrumb li:last-child a::after{display:none;}
#breadcrumb .heading{margin:0; font-size:1.6rem;}

/* Sidebar Navigation */
.sidebar nav{display:block; width:100%;}
.sidebar nav li{margin:0 0 3px 0; padding:0;}
.sidebar nav a{display:block; position:relative; margin:0; padding:5px 10px 5px 15px; text-decoration:none; border:solid; border-width:0 0 1px 0;}
.sidebar nav a::after{top:9px; left:5px; content:"\f101";}
.sidebar nav ul ul a{padding-left:35px;}
.sidebar nav ul ul a::after{left:25px;}
.sidebar nav ul ul ul a{padding-left:55px;}
.sidebar nav ul ul ul a::after{left:45px;}

/* Pagination */
.pagination{display:block; width:100%; text-align:center; clear:both;}
.pagination li{display:inline-block; margin:0 2px 0 0;}
.pagination li:last-child{margin-right:0;}
.pagination a, .pagination strong{display:block; padding:8px 11px; border:1px solid; background-clip:padding-box; font-weight:normal;}

/* Back to Top */
#backtotop{z-index:999; display:inline-block; position:fixed; visibility:hidden; bottom:20px; right:20px; width:36px; height:36px; line-height:36px; font-size:16px; text-align:center; opacity:.2; border-radius:50%; background-clip:padding-box;}
#backtotop i{display:block; width:100%; height:100%; line-height:inherit;}
#backtotop.visible{visibility:visible; opacity:.5;}
#backtotop:hover{opacity:1;}


/* Tables
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
table, th, td{border:1px solid; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top;}
table, th{table-layout:auto;}
table{width:100%; margin-bottom:15px;}
th, td{padding:5px 8px;}
td{border-width:0 1px;}


/* Gallery
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#gallery{display:block; width:100%; margin-bottom:50px;}
#gallery figure figcaption{display:block; width:100%; clear:both;}
#gallery li{margin-bottom:30px;}


/* Font Awesome Social Icons
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.faico{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.faico li{display:inline-block; margin:8px 5px 0 0; padding:0; line-height:normal;}
.faico li:last-child{margin-right:0;}
.faico a{display:inline-block; width:36px; height:36px; line-height:36px; font-size:18px; text-align:center; border-radius:50%; background-clip:padding-box;}

.faico a{color:#000000; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
.faico a:hover{color:#FFFFFF;}

.faicon-dribble:hover{background-color:#EA4C89;}
.faicon-facebook:hover{background-color:#3B5998;}
.faicon-google-plus:hover{background-color:#DB4A39;}
.faicon-linkedin:hover{background-color:#0E76A8;}
.faicon-twitter:hover{background-color:#00ACEE;}
.faicon-vk:hover{background-color:#4E658E;}


/* Colours
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
body{color:#474747; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
a{color:#6677BC;}
a:active, a:focus{background:transparent;}/* IE10 + 11 Bugfix - prevents grey background */
hr, .borderedbox{border-color:#D7D7D7;}
label span{color:#FF0000; background-color:inherit;}
input:focus, textarea:focus, *:required:focus{border-color:#6677BC;}
.overlay{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:inherit;}
.overlay::after{color:inherit; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.55);}

.btn, .btn.inverse:hover, a .icon, a.inverse:hover .icon{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#6677BC; border-color:#6677BC;}
.btn:hover, .btn.inverse, a:hover .icon, a.inverse .icon{color:inherit; background-color:transparent; border-color:inherit;}


/* Rows */
.row0, .row0 a{color:#CBCBCB; background-color:#000000; border-color:rgba(255,255,255,.2);}
.row1{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);}
.row2, .row2 a{}
.row3{color:#474747; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
.row4{color:#CBCBCB; background-color:#000000;}
.row5, .row5 a{color:#474747; background-color:#FFFFFF;}

.coloured{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#6677BC;}
.coloured .btn{color:inherit; background-color:transparent; border-color:inherit;}
.coloured .btn:hover{color:#6677BC; background-color:#FFFFFF;}


/* Top Bar */
#topbar, #topbar ul li{border-color:rgba(255,255,255,.2);}
#topbar > div:last-of-type li:first-child a{color:#6677BC;}


/* Header */
#header #logo a{color:inherit;}


/* Page Intro */
#pageintro footer input, #pageintro footer button{color:#000000; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
#pageintro footer button{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#6677BC;}

.flex-direction-nav a{color:rgba(255,255,255,1);}
.flex-control-paging li a{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1); border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0); border-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);}


/* Content Area */
#introblocks > ul > li > article{color:#474747; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
#introblocks > ul > li > article footer, #introblocks > ul > li > article footer a::after{border-color:#D7D7D7;}

#newsletter input, #newsletter button{color:#474747; border-color:#D7D7D7;}
#newsletter input{background-color:#FFFFFF;}
#newsletter input:focus{border-color:#6677BC;}
#newsletter button{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#6677BC;}


/* Footer */
#footer .heading{color:inherit;}
#footer nav a{color:inherit;}
#footer nav li:first-child a, #footer nav a:hover{color:#6677BC;}


/* Navigation */
#mainnav li a{color:inherit;}
#mainnav .active a, #mainnav a:hover, #mainnav li:hover > a{color:#6677BC; background-color:inherit;}
#mainnav li li a, #mainnav .active li a{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6); border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);}
#mainnav li li:hover > a, #mainnav .active .active > a{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#6677BC;}
#mainnav form select{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; border-color:rgba(136,136,136,.5);/* #888888 */}

#breadcrumb ul{border-color:rgba(255,255,255,.2);}
#breadcrumb a{color:inherit; background-color:inherit;}
#breadcrumb li:last-child a{color:#6677BC;}

.container .sidebar nav a{color:inherit; border-color:#D7D7D7;}
.container .sidebar nav a:hover{color:#6677BC;}

.pagination a, .pagination strong{border-color:#D7D7D7;}
.pagination .current *{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#6677BC;}

#backtotop{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#6677BC;}


/* Tables + Comments */
table, th, td, #comments .avatar, #comments input, #comments textarea{border-color:#D7D7D7;}
#comments input:focus, #comments textarea:focus, #comments *:required:focus{border-color:#6677BC;}
th{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#373737;}
tr, #comments li, #comments input[type="submit"], #comments input[type="reset"]{color:inherit; background-color:#FBFBFB;}
tr:nth-child(even), #comments li:nth-child(even){color:inherit; background-color:#F7F7F7;}
table a, #comments a{background-color:inherit;}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width;}


/* Max Wrapper Width - Laptop, Desktop etc.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media screen and (min-width:978px){
 .hoc{max-width:978px;}
}


/* Mobile Devices
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media screen and (max-width:900px){
 .hoc{max-width:90%;}

 #topbar{}

 #header{padding:30px 0;}
 #header #logo{margin-top:3px;}

 #mainnav{}
 #mainnav ul{display:none;}
 #mainnav form{display:block;}

 #breadcrumb{}

 .container{}
 #comments input[type="reset"]{margin-top:10px;}
 .pagination li{display:inline-block; margin:0 5px 5px 0;}

 #footer{}

 #copyright{}
 #copyright p:first-of-type{margin-bottom:10px;}
}


@media screen and (max-width:750px){
 .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev, .flex-direction-nav .flex-next{display:none;}
 .flex-control-nav{display:block;}

 .imgl, .imgr{display:inline-block; float:none; margin:0 0 10px 0;}
 .fl_left, .fl_right{display:block; float:none;}
 .one_half, .one_third, .two_third, .one_quarter, .two_quarter, .three_quarter{display:block; float:none; width:auto; margin:0 0 30px 0; padding:0;}

 #topbar{text-align:center;}
 #topbar ul{margin:0 0 15px 0;}
 #topbar div:last-child ul{margin:0;}

 #header{text-align:center;}
 #header #logo{margin:0 0 15px 0;}

 #introblocks > ul > li{margin-bottom:50px;}
 #introblocks > ul > li:last-child{margin-bottom:0;}

 .container{padding-bottom:50px;}/* Not neccessary - just looks better */
}


@media screen and (max-width:450px){
 #topbar ul li{margin-bottom:2px; padding-right:0; border-right:none;}

 #pageintro li footer form{max-width:none; width:100%;}
}


/* Other
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media screen and (max-width:650px){
 .scrollable{display:block; width:100%; margin:0 0 30px 0; padding:0 0 15px 0; overflow:auto; overflow-x:scroll;}
 .scrollable table{margin:0; padding:0; white-space:nowrap;}

 .inline li{display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}
 .pushright li{margin-right:0;}

 .font-x2{font-size:1.4rem;}
 .font-x3{font-size:1.6rem;}

 #pageintro li article{max-width:none; width:100%;}
 #pageintro li .heading{font-size:1.6rem;}
}
```

```html
div class="bgded overlay" style="background-image:url('../imagini/01.png');" > 
  <div class="wrapper row1">
  </div>
  <div id="pageintro" class="hoc clear"> 
    <div class="flexslider basicslider">
 
 <!--==================
   Slides
 ====================-->
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <article>
            <p></p>
            <h3 class="heading">Vezi Magazinul Nostru</h3>
            <p>Vezi o Panorama cu Interiorul Magazinului</p>
            <footer><a class="btn inverse" href="imagini/Panorama/panorama.jpg">Vezi Panorama</a></footer>
          </article>
```

So. im doing this for my job, im still new to this, so i am learning as i am working, on the pc it look as i wanted it pictures all fit well and all, but on mobile the background images are a bit wierd it's like the phone zooms on the backgrond image only, everything else is fine, only bakground images are messy.

images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DerYs.jpg

Comment: Could you share a screenshot desktop vs mobile + show the html/css thanks

Comment: Please edit your post with code snipet dont put it in the comment

Comment: edited so you can see

Comment: There is special tools when you write a post in stackoverflow that let you paste code and drops images. Use them.

Comment: tryed kept getting an error

Comment: there, i am not allowed to put images in posts, but found the code

Comment: Could you post also the css..

Comment: done, that should be the css

Comment: @RefchiDenis you should look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images. I guess this should solve your problem. But if still need some help try using codepen or jsfiddle and share your code.

Comment: Try adding a <div class="container"> around all of this

Comment: nothing worked.

Answer (score -1):

Explore the key CSS `background-image` property that lets us respond to those characteristics and `Media Queries` that lets us respond to responsiveness on a device screen sizes.

There are several Approach to things like this, First, you have a large image for Desktop and Small Image for Mobile, if you do, you can work with this code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    #image { 
        background-image: url(largeimage.jpg); 
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        #image { 
            background-image: url(smallimage.jpg); 
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image"></div>
</body>
```

Or you can work with this code below

```
#image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(image.jpg); 
}
```

Either case always be sure to optimize even the high-resolution images as much as possible

Comment: Which did you try? the first?

Comment: it also does this thing when i refresh it shows the normal size for a second until the slide pops up and than it zooms in

Comment: i tryed both of them

Comment: i also tryed to get a smaller res for the phone but it still zomes in

Comment: the html code that you gave me does not change anything i tryed with a really really small resolution